# Mathematical equations using if-else statements

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, math, var

I'm getting a few errors whilst using a test script to achieve a particular result.

I want to calculate a **word-list** from a document which is stored in a folder and then

the variable `"wword"` is the amount of words that were CORRECT. There's a total of 17 words. This number (15) of course will be changed base on user input, therefor the reasoning of the variable `"wword"`

The current problems that I have is "unary operator expected" and that this line of code `gradel=$('"$wword"' - 17)` is not inserting the `$wword` variable as it should be 15. What am I doing wrong?

```
wword="15"

gradel=$('"$wword"' - 17)
gradel=$('"$gradel"' / 17)



if [ "$gradel" => "1" ] 
then 
  gradel="A+" 

elif [ "$gradel" => ".90" ] 
then
  gradel="A"

elif [ "$gradel" => ".85" ] 
then
  gradel=“B+”

elif [ "$gradel" => ".80" ] 
then
  gradel=“B”

elif [ "$gradel" => ".75" ] 
then
  gradel=“C”

elif [ "$gradel" =>  ".70" ] 
then
  gradel=“C-”

elif [ "$gradel" => ".65" ] 
then
  gradel="D"

else
  gradel="F"   

fi

echo "$gradel"
```

Comment: Can't do floating point arithmetic/comparisons in bash, use bc or awk etc.

Comment: Many small things. `$()` is command substitution, but you want `$(())` for arithmetic expansion. `'"$var"'` expands to `"$var"`; single quotes prevent expansion. You use non-standard double quotes `”` in some places. You have to compare numbers with `-ge`, `-gt` etc. instead of `>=`, `>` etc. Bash can't deal with floating point numbers.

Comment: @BenjaminW. okay, i've updated the coded. If you see above, the only error I'm getting is the `gradel=$((grade/17))` isn't calculating..why?

Comment: Because Bash can't do floating point calculations. 15/17 in integer division is zero.

Comment: @BenjaminW. What can I do to fix this? theres gotta be an easy solution to what it is I'm doing...

Comment: Also, don't change the code. Your question isn't supposed to be an ever morphing construct representing the latest state of a work in progress. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I'm writing up a little program that does it all in `bc`, give me a minute.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks Ben!

Comment: @JamesDean : You could use Zsh instead of bash. Zsh can do floats, unless you are using a very old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic, so you'll need a tool that can do that, such as awk. Here is an example:

```
wword=$1
grade=$((17-wword))
awk -v g="$grade" 'BEGIN{a=g/17}a>=$1{print $2;exit}' << EOF
1    A+
0.9  A
0.85 B+
0.80 B
0.75 C
0.70 C-
0.65 D
-1   F
EOF
```

Comment: When using your code in BASH, this is the error I'm receiving: awk: `invalid -v option`

Comment: @JamesDean what platform are you on? Try with a space after `v` like in the edited answer

Comment: Okay, that worked. Now, how does the AWK command work? Can you break it down as to how it's calculating; then using the EOF parameters to give a grade? Sorry, still learning here...

Comment: also, how can I get the answer from your code into a variable?

Comment: okay, I know how to add a variable.Only problem is, if the user gets 0 words wrong, your code equals Grade A rather than Grade A+

Comment: @JamesDean: With GNU awk on Ubuntu I get A+ for 0. Did you include the equal in `>=` in the condition? If yes, it could be a floating point error, so you could fix it by subtracting a small value, like `a>=$1-0.0001`. Alternatively, you could replace `1` with `0.99999` in the heredoc. Re the explanation, what part exactly don't you understand, so I can explain better?

Answer (score 1):

There are many small problems in this program:

- You're trying to do arithmetics in

  ```
  gradel=$('"$wword"' - 17)
  ```

  but this actually tries to run the contents of `$( )` as a command. You want `$(( ))` for arithmetic expansion.
- `'"$wword"'` expands to `"$wword"`: the single quotes prevent expansion. You want `"$wword"`. (Within `$(( ))`, even just `wword` is enough).
- You're comparing numbers in `[ ]` with `=>`. If anything, it should be `>=`, and for numbers in `[ ]` you should use `-ge` instead anyway.
- `gradel=“B+”` uses non-standard double quotes.

And the biggest problem: Bash can't do floating point calculations. People often use [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) for that (or awk, Perl, Python...). This is a little bc program that does what you want to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/bc -q
# -q suppresses the copryight message

# Use floating point with three digits after period
scale = 3

# Read from standard input
wword = read()
gradel = (17 - wword) / 17

if (gradel >= 1) {
    print "A+\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.9) {
    print "A\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.85) {
    print "B+\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.8) {
    print "B\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.75) {
    print "C\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.7) {
    print "C-\n"
} else if (gradel >= 0.65) {
    print "D\n"
} else {
    print "F\n"
}

quit
```

Used like this:

```
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 5.5 6; do ./so <<< "$i"; done
A+
A
B+
B
C
C-
D
F
```

where `so` is the name of the script.

---

In general, if all you want is a single (or a few) floating point comparison(s) as part of a Bash script, you could embed bc as follows:

```
if (( $(bc <<< "$var > 0.9") )); then
    echo "$var is greater than 0.9"
else
    echo "$var is not greater than 0.9"
fi
```

where `"$var"` is the Bash floating point variable you want to compare to `0.9`.

This takes advantage of bc printing `1` for a true comparison and `0` for a false comparison. `(( ))` then converts that to an exit status.

Comment: Ben, do I need to create a separate script when using ` #!/usr/bin/bc -q` ?

Comment: @JamesDean Yes, the script goes into a separate file. I'll add a blurb about embedding bc floating point comparisons into a Bash script.